# Open generic injection via factory in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to be able to inject a service with a generic constrained to an interface in Angular, using a common factory... I can do it if I declare a provider of every injected type, but that defeats the purpose of why I want it this way.

What I want is something like:

```js
interface WorkerServiceContract {
  doWork(): void;
}

class MyService<T extends WorkerServiceContract> {
  constructor(private worker: T) {}

  doWorkWrapper() { this.worker.doWork(); }
}
```

So at any point I can do a:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class FooWorkerService implements WorkerServiceContract {
   doWork() { console.log('foo'); }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class BarWorkerService implements WorkerServiceContract {
   doWork() { console.log('bar'); }
}

@Component(/*blabla*/)
class MyComponent {
   constructor(private fooWorker: MyService<FooWorkerService>, private barWorker: MyService<BarWorkerService>) {}
}
```

I understand I can declare the injection using specific tokens for each of the `WorkerServiceContract` possibilities, but I'm wondering if there's a way (I've looked through the documentation but couldn't figure it out), to have it "open"... so I could do **something like** (this wouldn't obviously work):

```js
providers: [
   {
      provide: MyService<T extends ServiceWorker>
      useFactory: (worker: T) => new MyService<T>(worker);
      deps: [T]
   }
]
```

I understand that's not possible in the provider definition (since it doesn't know `T`), but is there any mechanism which would allow something "generic" like this to work? It's probably something obvious but I can seem to get my head around to do it

I'm using Angular 9

---

#### Real-Life scenario (addendum)

The whole rationale about why we want this (the real-life scenario) is:

I have a tool-generated service class (from Swagger/OpenApi). For that service, I create a proxy/wrapper service that intercepts all the http (not http, but the methods, which do more than just calling the http client) calls to the API and pipes the returned observables to handle errors (and successes, actually) to show UI notifications (and create other calls to diagnostic logging servers, etc.).

These handlers are sometimes are generic, but each view (depending on the called API) may want to have their own handlers (e.g., one may show a toast, one may show a popup, one might want to transform the call to the API in some ways, or whatever).

I could do it on every call to the API, but on my team, we've found out that separating those concerns (the handling of a successful call with normal data received from the API, and the handling of errors) helps both the readability and size of the code of the components (and the responsibility of each code). We've already solved that by a "simple" call on the constructor, e.g.:

```js
constructor(private apiService: MyApiService) {
  this.apiService = apiService.getProxyService<MyErrorHandler>();
}
```

Which returns a `Proxy` that handles all that. **This works just fine**, but we were discussing the idea of making it "even cleaner", like so:

```js
constructor(private apiService: MyApiService<MyErrorHandler>) {}
```

And have a factory on the DI container create that proxy for us, which would bring the benefit of both: a) not having to remember doing that call on the constructor, and b) have a clear view of ALL the dependencies (including the error handler) directly on the constructor parameters (without having to dig into the constructor code, which could have other stuff depending on the actual component)

And no, an `HttpClient` interceptor wouldn't work here, since the auto-generated service does more than the `HttpClient` call (and we want to work on what gets returned from that service, not directly on the `HttpResponse` object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Perhaps to try an injector with tokens

```js
const services = new Map();
const myService = <T>(service: T): InjectionToken<MyService<T>> => {
  if (services.has(service)) {
    return services.get(service);
  }

  const token = new InjectionToken<<T>(t: T) => MyService<T>>(`${Math.random()}`, {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: injector => new MyService(injector.get(service)),
    deps: [Injector],
  });

  services.set(service, token);
  return token;
};

class MyComponent {
   constructor(
     @Inject(myService(FooWorkerService)) private foo: MyService <FooWorkerService>,
     @Inject(myService(BarWorkerService)) private bar: MyService <BarWorkerService>,
   ) {
  }
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

You are right, generics aren't present after transpilation and therefore can't be used as providers.

To solve it you need to inject factory itself in your component. Because anyway you would specify type of the generic, now you need bit more code to achieve desired behavior.

you can use

```js
const MY_SERVICE_FACTORY = new InjectionToken<<T>(t: T) => MyService<T>>('MY_SERVICE_FACTORY', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => worker => new MyService(worker),
});

// just a helper to extract type, can be omitted
export type InjectionTokenType<Type> = Type extends InjectionToken<infer V> ? V : never;

class MyComponent {
   constructor(
     @Inject(MY_SERVICE_FACTORY) private serviceFactory: InjectionTokenType<typeof MY_SERVICE_FACTORY>,
     foo: FooWorkerService,
     bar: BarWorkerService,
   ) {
   this.fooWorker = this.serviceFactory(foo);
   this.barWorker = this.serviceFactory(bar);
  }
}
```

also to keep the code cleaner in the constructor you can move it to the providers of the component.

```js
@Component({
  // blabla
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'foo',
      useFactory: t => new MyService(t),
      deps: [FooWorkerService],
    },
    {
      provide: 'bar',
      useFactory: t => new MyService(t),
      deps: [BarWorkerService],
    },
  ],
})
class MyComponent {
   constructor(
     @Inject('foo') private fooWorker: MyService<FooWorkerService>,
     @Inject('bar') private barWorker: MyService<BarWorkerService>,
   ) {}
}
```

Comment: I was afraid something like this was the only way. The current way I solve it is having the `MyService` have a kind of `getActualService<T>(): T` method which I call on the constructor (and acts as my factory), without defining a specific provider. This is what I wanted to avoid through DI (avoid having to do extra steps on the constructor of the type using the service, I mean), but yes, doesn't look like it's possible :-/

I'll +1 your answer for now and wait to see if other answers come in. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've added one more example how to keep code cleaner in the class by moving things to providers, but anyway it requires usage factory for every type.

Comment: Thanks for the edit: yes, what I meant was "avoiding to have extra usage on the component using the service" (not just the constructor, but all of it), while also not having to declare the provider for each of the possible "workerServices" (there will be a lot of those in real usage).

If I have to do that, the `getService<T>()` method on `MyService` looks as the "cleanest" possible way, and I do the "hacky stuff" (just use the injector in that method to dynamically get the instance) on `MyService` (which is already a "hacky" service involving `Proxy` objects and stuff)

Comment: I've edited and added a "real-life scenario" part where I explain why we want this, just in case it could bring more ideas up. Again thank you for your time :-)

Comment: Great, I'll check tonight, perhaps something comes into my head.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck on my side. I came up with `@Inject(findService(FooWorkerService)) private fooWorker: MyService<FooWorkerService>`, but it always requires to specify `@Inject`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm going for a solution involving @Inject too, but I haven't had time to actually go and implement it yet. I'll try tomorrow and If it works I'll post it here

Comment: I've given up... I tried the way of trying to add injection tokens dynamically (or have a list and resolve them with a custom decorator), but the lifetime of everything doesn't want to help (modules get instantiated first, then it calls the decorators on the classes, not the other way around), and I can't mess with the module injector after it's been created, it seems (i can create new injector instances but can't tell angular to use it automatically, so the @Inject metadata won't use my injector). I'm giving up and will keep using the call on the constructor. I'll accept your answer here

Comment: Crazy, I've never debugged `@Inject` so deeply but always thought it shares logic with Injector service too... good to know :) thank you too!

Comment: Wait, I guess I have an idea, I've added 3rd option, might you check it? It requires injector and tokens and I guess can work if angular can detect dynamic tokens.

Comment: That did it! Not -directly- (because in my actual case, `MyService` can be many) but I think I can work around what's missing!! Yup, that worked!! :-)

Just as a nitpick, on the `InjectionToken` options, the factory receives no parameters, but you can inject anything on it using the `inject` method exported in `@angular/core`

Comment: Nice!!! Please update my answer with the final solution when you have time, looking forward to see it.

Comment: Yup... I basically could make it already by having a `@WithHandler(MyService, Handler) private service: MyService` parameter... now I want to remove the redundant `MyService` in the decorator, but finding the type of the parameter is proving hard... I'm working on it on my "break time". Will post with the final solution when I get it :-)

Comment: No dice with the decorator... also has problems with AOT if the decorator is not -specifically- `@Inject`  (probably something to do with angular doing static analysis instead of working with the annotated metadata from the decorators). So the most I can do is `@Inject(Method(ServiceType, HandlerType)) serviceType: ServiceType`. This solves having all the dependencies shown on the constructor parameters, however I see it a bit redundant. I'll check with my team if they prefer this to a simple call on the constructor. I wished I could spend more time on this, but I can't. Thanks again!!

Comment: I see, some tools are always trying to be smarter than they should :) It was a nice question! Happy coding!